# Tool to get xy coordinates in curve

Tags: android, iphone, photoshop, game-physics

I'm looking for a tool/way to get the XY coordinates of a line  in a picture for a video game so i can force the player to be above this curve.

The only way I have for now is to go through the curve by hand and record the points via a surface like Android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it depends, what do you mean by 'curve'?

I would not define it as a function such as: `double getY(double x)`

I think the best way to do it is defining an array of points and forcing positions on the segments `segment(point[i], point[i+1])`

Comment: Thanks for you response. i just want to get the coordinates of a curve in a picture like this one (the snake curve)http://www.takegreatpictures.com/app/webroot/content/2010_images/2007/05/22/s_curve_sand_dune.jpg

Comment: as i said i would go with linear interpolation... then you can decide the right number of 'waypoints'